# How to plot scipy.stats.norm(x,y) with matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy

Given 2 values, mean and std, I want to use matplotlib to plot the function scipy.stats.norm(mean, std). How can I do it?

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to plot?  The [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)?  The [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the loc and scale parameters for the mean and the standard deviation, respectively.

**PDF:**

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)

mean = 10
std = 1

plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x, loc=mean, scale=std))
plt.show()
```

[image]

or **CDF**:

```
plt.plot(x, norm.cdf(x, loc=mean, scale=std))
```

[image]